# NativeScript Vue send request with form data (multipart/form-data)

Tags: nativescript, multipartform-data, binary-data, nativescript-vue

I have a case in my application where I need to send data as form data to a server. The data includes a message and an optional list of files. The problem I'm facing is that when sending the request it's not being formed properly.

**Request Payload**

*Expected (sample with the same request in the browser)*

[image: Expected Request Payload]

*Actual (resulting request when running in NativeScript)*
[image: Actual Request Payload]

The actual result is that the payload is somehow being URL encoded.

**Code example**

```js
sendData({ id, message, files }) {
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }
  };

  const payload = new FormData();
  payload.append('message', message);

  if (files && files.length > 0) {
    files.forEach((file) => {
      payload.append(`files`, file, file.name);
    });
  }

  return AXIOS_INSTANCE.post(
    `/api/save/${id}`,
    payload,
    config
  );
}
```

As you can see from the above, I'm using `axios` and also I'm trying to use `FormData` to format the data. From my research it seems that NativeScript used to not support binary data via XHR - however looking at [this merge request on GitHub](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/pull/7707) it looks like it's been fixed about a year ago.

So my suspicion is that I'm doing something wrong, maybe there's an alternative to using `FormData`, or else I shouldn't use `axios` for this particular request?

**Version Numbers**

- `nativescript` **6.8.0**
- `tns-android` **6.5.3**
- `tns-ios` **6.5.3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nativescript's [background-http](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-background-http) supports multipart form data.

See below for how its configured to do multipart upload

```js
var bghttp = require("nativescript-background-http");
var session = bghttp.session("image-upload");
var request = {
  url: url,
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream"
  },
  description: "Uploading "
};

var params = [
  { name: "test", value: "value" },
  { name: "fileToUpload", filename: file, mimeType: "image/jpeg" }
];
var task = session.multipartUpload(params, request);
```

Comment: Great thanks - that worked perfectly. Honestly I did see some other posts mentioning this package but was trying to see if I can do without it.. but anyway it's working great :)